# Is it true that "std::forward" and "std::move" do not generate code?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move, perfect-forwarding

Is it true that "std::forward" and "std::move" do not generate code? I saw this saying in << An Effective C++11/14 Sampler >>. The related code is at the footnote. Could somebody explain the code in detail? I would be very grateful to have some help with this question.

As per the documentation(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00416_source.html), which says that:

```
   /**
    *  @brief  Forward an lvalue.
    *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
    *
    *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
    */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr _Tp&&
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
     { return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t); }



  /**
    *  @brief  Forward an rvalue.
    *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
    *
    *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
    */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr _Tp&&
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
     {
       static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template argument"
                     " substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type");
       return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
     }
    /**
    *  @brief  Convert a value to an rvalue.
    *  @param  __t  A thing of arbitrary type.
    *  @return The parameter cast to an rvalue-reference to allow moving it.
   */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
     move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
     { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

Comment: That's not true. It generates code: https://godbolt.org/z/DthcYe

Comment: @Thomas Sablik Thank you for the clarification. I see. It's a good way to verify whether it's true or false. Since there is some assembly code corresponding to the C++ code indeed, maybe I can draw the conclusion that the compiler(`x86-64 clang 10.0.0`) use the libstdc++ code aforementioned in my question. Am I right?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Quote: "As per the documentation(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ **libstdc++** /latest-doxygen/a00416_source.html), which says that:". I mentioned it **implicitly**.      :)

Comment: No, you can't. You would have to download that library. build it and compile the code to make it sure. You can use different compilers with different standard libraries. You can't see which standard library is used at godbolt and you can't see which source code is used for your pre-built library.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I see. Could you please explain the code snippet aforementioned in the question? There is some assembly code corresponding to the C++ code indeed.

Comment: In practice std::move nor std::forwrd generates no code, as all intermediate steps like std::remove reference will be removed from optimizer. To show that switching of the optimizer lives intermediate code in the executable is only good to see when code is generated and optimized later away. In fact I never saw with real code and standard optimization such extra code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik *"can't see which standard library is used at godbolt"* You can, it's not hard: `#ifndef __GLIBCXX__` `#error` `#endif`. You can even get the version of libstdc++ by examining the value of the macro.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right. It's simple to find out. I provided a link. If someone is interested in the version of the used standard library you provided a way to find out.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat & ThomasSablik Thanks to both of you. Where's the link. I have tried but I failed.

Comment: It's in my first comment.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The link does not work. I mean the code is same with the former one. No modification could be seen indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether something "generates code" or not depends on the compiler and its settings. As the other answer shows, you can expect some extra code to be generated **if the optimizations are disabled**.

`std::move` and `std::forward` merely return a reference to the parameter, which doens't require any actions at runtime (the change in value category happens at compile-time), and if optimizations are enabled, any half-decent compiler will generate no code for them.

If you want no extra code to be generated even in debug builds, use a `static_cast<T &&>` instead of those functions.

Comment: I have seen such statement which says `std::forward` is the same with "static_cast<T &&>". Since you also make the same statement in your answer, I think the saying is true. One more question raises,  why does not implement the `std::forward` as `static_cast<T&&>` which looks simpler?

Comment: @John It's already implemented as `static_cast`: `return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. One more question raises, as these functions invoke static_cast<_Tp&&> indeed, why does not extra code would be generated even in debug builds if I use a static_cast<T &&> instead of those functions? I am a little confused.

Comment: @John Because with a `static_cast`, there no function to call, so no function-calling code will be generated, and no code for the function (`std::move`) will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. It generates code. The code

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b = std::move(a);
}
```

generates this assembly with Clang 10.0 (without optimization):

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 4]
        call    std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        xor     ecx, ecx
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rax]
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], edx
        mov     eax, ecx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&): # @std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

and the code

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b = a;
}
```

generates this assembly with Clang 10.0 (without optimization):

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], ecx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/DthcYe

Comment: It makes no sense to switch of optimization in general to compare code generation. std::move is only a cast and it generates no code at all, even if in an intermediate step removes references via a function call which will allways be removed by optimizer. It is only an academic result to say "it generates code" as in no real circumstance one will be run c++ code without optimization ( maybe while debugging, but thats an other topic ).

Comment: @Klaus I know a large company that builds all production artifacts (server applications, million lines of code) with `-O0`. It's not academic. It's the real world.

Comment: Yes, I also know a large company where people compiles code with UB and switch of optimzers to get any working executable. But is that the problem which we want to talk about? If production code is generated with O0, there is something wrong with people, company and the customer!

Comment: @Klaus _"But is that the problem which we want to talk about?"_ OP asked if `std::move` produces code. The answer is yes. OP didn't ask if the optimizer can remove most of it.

Comment: The answer is: Only if you use seldom/rare/strange conditions! :-)

Comment: @ThomasSablik & Klaus Thanks to both of you.  I understand it to some degree with your generous help. Could you please explain the related code aforementioned in the question?

Comment: @John _"If the answer is yes, could somebody explain the code in detail?"_ But my answer is no. You should ask in the other answer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you for the same. I reedited the question.  :) At the same time, I would go out of my way to dig deep.